# UIImageView.image is always nil after assigning a valid UIImage

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UIImageView` in a view of a `StoryBoard`, `IBOutlet` connections are made properly (have double and triple checked this), the images to display are added to the proper target, etc. (Have been debugging this for a day now) the `UIImageView` display images if I set them in Interface Builder.

But if I set the `UIImageView.image` property to a valid `UIImage` (I can see even the preview when debugging) loaded with any image it always shows the first image, not the new one, or if I left it blank in IB it keeps nil value.

This only happens in this view if I try the same thing in another view of the StoryBoard and the `UIImageView` properly shows the content of the UIImage.

Any clues will we greatly appreciated.

Edited:

Thanks for the replies, has tested also setting it from a button, the code is this code:

The property declaration is:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *theRecomendationImage;
```

Have Tested with weak and strong, just to be sure.

The `IBAction` implementation (tested it gets called)

```
- (IBAction)changeImage {

    UIImage *theImageToTint = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sunny"];
//    theImageToTint = [theImageToTint imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    self.theRecomendationImage.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    self.theRecomendationImage.image = theImageToTint;
}
```

When debugging if you check the value of theImageToTint it is a valid image (not nil) and you can even quicklook the image. But when I assign it to the `UIImageView` the value is always nil. No error, just keep nil.

Thanks for your interest, and sorry for the incomplete question.

Edited:

If you execute

```
po self.theRecomendationImage.image
```

in the debug console before and after executing the assignment:  self.theRecomendationImage.image = theImageToTint; the value is nil.

Edited:

If you add the `UIImageView` by code, it works and get updated when you assign a new image to it, this takes me to point to some `Storyboard` issue.

Is there any tool to verify a storyboard?

Comment: can you show me some code for example where you set this UIImage?

Comment: Without seeing any code (which you should post). I am guessing you are setting the image in `viewDidLoad` or some other similar method. If this is the case try setting it in `viewWillAppear:`
Again, without seeing code I am just taking a shot in the dark.

Comment: yes @Firo is what i think as well :)

Comment: I know you said that the `IBOutlet` is connected properly but print `self.theRecomendationImage` in this method and see if it is nil.

Comment: Have you figured this one out? I have the same issue on iOS7 but works on iOS6.1.

Comment: Did you solve this problem yet? I got the same behavior and can´t find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the image format is `.png` instead of `.jpg` or any other.